# Rigid body rotation

Tags: geometry, rotations, rigid-transformation

The problem I am trying to solve is that I am trying to rotate a rigid body and align it to the X axis in 3D space. I have chosen two points on the body (p1, p2). First I move the coordinates to align the origin to one of the two points. (Cartesian coordinates)

Then, I compute the angles with respect to XYZ
$$\overrightarrow{dirVect}=p1-p2$$
$$ \angle{X} = cos^{-1} \left(\frac{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.\overrightarrow{dirVect}}{|\overrightarrow{dirVect}|}\right)$$
$$ \angle{Y} = cos^{-1} \left(\frac{\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.\overrightarrow{dirVect}}{|\overrightarrow{dirVect}|}\right)$$
$$ \angle{Z} = cos^{-1} \left(\frac{\begin{bmatrix}0& 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.\overrightarrow{dirVect}}{|\overrightarrow{dirVect}|}\right)$$

I now compute a Rotation Matrix for ([using this MATLAB script](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9289-dcm-from-euler-angles/content/dcmfromeulerang/dcmfromeuler.m))

$\angle{X}, \frac{\pi}{2}-\angle{Y},\frac{\pi}{2}-\angle{Z}$

on applying this rotation matrix to every point on the rigid body, I expect the point p2 to be on the X axis (X, 0, 0). It is not. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Formatting guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If your matrix is doing the wrong thing, then maybe your matrix is wrong. If your matrix is being produced by a program you trust, then maybe your inputs to the program are wrong. A lot of things that aren't depicted here could have gone wrong...

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9289-dcm-from-euler-angles/content/dcmfromeulerang/dcmfromeuler.m is what I am using to generate the rotatian matrix. I am running these step by step and things seem to make sense at all steps.

Comment: Where is p2 winding up in your trials?

Comment: It is slightly off https://www.dropbox.com/s/6l2zi9z8et7l1vu/TEST.fig (MATLAB) Angles were calculated as X:0.95475 Y:89.8932 Z:89.0512 (degrees) the blue is the original and the red is the rotated position